# I am unable to insert 10000 records. Getting Too man query rows error

Tags: apex, class, exception, dmlexception

```java
public class CreateBulkAccounts {
    @future
    Public static void method1()
    {
        List<Account> acList = new List<Account>();
        
        for(integer i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            Account a = new Account ();
            a.Name = 'Test' + i;
            acList.add(a);
        }
        insert acList;
        //system.debug('Accountlist size'+acList.size());
    }
}
```

I read a lot of posts everyone is saying when you query record more than 10000 then it throws an error like this but don't query anything then why its throw an error like that? I know we can do this by batch but why not through the future method?

Comment: Hi, Are you not facing while saving the code. You did not define the List Variable for List<Account>. It should be as below '`ist <Account> acList=new List <Account>() ;` and also Future is not required on this scenerio.

Comment: i have inititialized the list as it is mentioned in the code . I have removed future but same error "Too many query rows:50001

Answer (score 0):

Future method is not required in the above scenario.

```
public class CreateBulkAccounts {
       Public static void method1() { 
            List <Account> acList=new List <Account>() ;

    for(integer i=0; i<10000; i++)
                {
            Account a= new Account ();
            a.Name='Test'+i;
            acList.add(a);
            }
insert acList; //system.debug('Accountlist size'+acList.size()); }

}
}
```

There may be some trigger or some custom logic on Account object which is causing the SOQL error . The trigger need to be bulkified. If there is no trigger on Account object as we are using only one DML these records will be inserted without any issue.

And also as you asked why this cannot be done using @Future but can be done using Batch.

```
**Batch Apex:** 

Batch apex allows you to define a job that can be divided into manageable chunks, where each chunk can be proceed separately.

In batch apex, it will fetch all records which you want perform the field update and divide them into list of 200 records and every 200 records operation is performed separately.


Batch Apex is used to separate tasks that are going to handle more records(complex long running jobs) in background process. Batch Apex also runs asynchronously.
If Batch Apex is not used for handling bulk records, we will hit governor limits set by Salesforce.com.

**Future Annotation:**  @future

Future Annotation is used to separate methods that are to be executed asynchronously.
```